# How to read files that contain a certain number/word in R?

Tags: r, file, design-patterns

I have a huge number of files and the filenames look like this:

```
 AL0201A0000500100day.1-1-2011
 AL0201A0000700100dymax.1-1-2011
 AL0201A0000900100day.1-1-2011
 AT0ILL10000400100day.1-1-1997
 AT0HBG10000700500hour8.1-1-1995
```

And I only want to read the files that contain for example 00007. The files are in different folders and subfolders.

How do I do that? I totally fail to use the * function in R. I know how to do that in Python, but I get nowhere in R. :/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not totally sure what you're asking, but maybe `myFiles <- list.files(pattern="00007")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find files whose name contains "00007", in the current working directory and all sub-directories with:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = '00007', recursive = T)
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working now, I dont know why I didnt get that by myself :/

Comment: Oh one more question that comes up now. How can I use 2 conditions? I only want files with 00007 and day (not in the example I used).

Comment: @Essi Not very clear what you're asking, but perhaps you mean: `pattern = '00007.*day'`

Comment: Ah yes!! Thanks! That is what I wanted! :) Thank you very much!